# phone call communication between mobile app users

Tags: android, ios, phone-call, privacy

I'm interested in integrating phone call communication between my app users. I'm trying to gather information on implementation solutions and guidelines.

From what I've gathered there is an option to use in-app call services where the application would handle the communication using VOIP while potentially masking the actual personal data?
Use some sort of phone proxy to secure personal data?
Whereas an alternative simple solution is asking the user for authorization and providing his phone number to the other user.

I'm not sure which methodology to use, if there are use cases which one is okay and one is not. For instance, Uber has an in app communication system which secures the users data, while on the other hand Google Maps which connects users with businesses, uses the phone's calling service.

All my searches on Google came up empty handed, if anyone has gone through this process and or has access to any development principles and guidelines on this topic I'd be grateful. Thanks!